# Is it wise to define connection variables?

Tags: php, definition

I'm here today to ask if it's wise to `define();` connection variables to a database. My Example is as followed:

```
// Constants For Database 
define ("DBAHost", "localhost");
define ("DBAUsername", "xxx");
define ("DBAPassword", "xxx");
define ("DBADB", "xxx");
```

and the connection handled;

```
class ClassWork
{       
    public function AllowDB ($Arg1)
    {
        if ($Arg1 === 1)
        {
            $MySQLi = new mysqli(DBAHost, DBAUsername, DBAPassword, DBADB);
            return 'Success... ' . mysqli_get_host_info($MySQLi);
        }
        elseif ($Arg1 !== 1)
        {
            return 'Wrong Argument Please Consult The Documentation!';
        }
    }
}
```

Or rather modify the accept datbase connection strings to push through the public function?

Comment: What does class ClassWork and method AllowDB do?

Comment: Class work is a class containing all production code which is in use by a few developers, we haven't got around to migrating it over to a named space because not all of our developers understand the usage; AllowDB  connects to the database and will be used as a connection variable for the other class functions

Comment: @YourCommonSense Which sparks another question, how am I able to communicate to databases from the first public function?

Answer (score 1):

A pure object-oriented way would be to pass in any needed parameters to a class instance.

That said, depending on your needs, it is acceptable to use a globally defined database instance.  Just keep in mind that you won't be able to easily juggle multiple databases later without refactoring.  You are boxing yourself in a bit with this method.

Comment: With this package I am only required to use 1 database.. So with this method, I feel that Yes I am boxing myself in; but it limits myself to one database and keep inside my requirements.. but what i'm trying to find out, is that using `define();` is it safe? can these constants be latched and echoed out in a development console or something?

Comment: @user1968541, What do you mean, is it safe?  Anything you define server-side stays server-side until you send it to the client.

Comment: Which sparks another question, how am I able to communicate to databases from the first public function?

Comment: @user1968541, You would need to have a member variable on your ClassWork class that contains a reference to the database connection instance.

Comment: could you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

You're talking of constants, not variables.
There is not much sense in a constant which is going to be used only once.
Better create an array with settings and pass it to your database wrapper class.